# 3 Different Main-Div and will show inside main-div and close main div when click another main div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi Im just new in jquery and javascript. What im trying to do is i have 3 separate Main-Divs ex main-div1, main-div2, main-div-3 all of them is one big box and when you click main-div1 it will show the contents of it but when you click main-div2 while different main div is open it will automatic close and open the main div.

HTML

```html
<a href="link">
    <div class="main-div1" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;">
        <div class="content"> Any contents </div>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="link">
    <div class="main-div2" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;">
        <div class="content"> Any contents </div>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="link">
    <div class="main-div3" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;">
        <div class="content"> Any contents </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: what you are tried so far? post your js code also

Answer (score 1):

All of the provided answers so far will do the job perfectly.

I've made an example that does pretty much the same, but instead of simply showing and hiding the divs, I've added the jQuery sliding animation. I personally like this animation a lot for these particular cases, so I thought I'd just throw it in there.

I've also wrapped the content with another div. This way you can provide the blocks with a title, so you actually have something for the user to click on.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scrfbe95/

If you click on a div that is already open it will simply close that div, otherwise this div will be opened and all others will close.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-div1" class="main-div">
  Main div 1
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content 1</p> 
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main-div2" class="main-div">
  Main div 2
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content 2</p> 
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main-div3" class="main-div">
  Main div 3
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content 3</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-div > .content {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
  $(document).on('click','.main-div',function() { showMainDiv($(this)); });

  function showMainDiv($el) {
    var $elContent = $el.find('.content');
    if ($elContent.is(':visible')) {
      $elContent.stop(true,true).slideUp(500);
    }
    else {
      $('.main-div').find('.content').stop(true,true).not($elContent).slideUp(500);
      $elContent.slideDown(500);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you "main-div" classes. Or use id if there's a 1 2 and 3. They are all main divs and each of them are supposed to do the same thing. If you want a div to be special use an id.

```
<div class="main-div" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;"> 
<p> Content 1 </p> 
</div>
<div class="main-div" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;"> 
<p> Content 2 </p> 
</div>
<div class="main-div" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;"> 
<p> Content 3 </p> 

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".main-div").click(function(){
    $(".main-div p").css("display","none");
    $(this).find("p").css("display","block")
});
```

CSS

```
.main-div p{
display: none;
}

.main-div{
height: 100px;
}
```

You have to give main-div at least some height to be able to see it since there's nothing else right now.

The jquery basicly hides every `p` elements inside your main div and then show the `p` element inside the current clicked main div.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a collapsible element! It's very easy to implement, since you're beginning with javascript, I think you want to go with jQuery. Don't mind what people say about jQuery being stupid, it's perfect for this case.

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="collapsible-div main-div1">
  <p>content 1</p>
</div>

<div class="collapsible-div main-div2">
  <p>content 2</p>
</div>

<div class="collapsible-div main-div3">
  <p>content 3</p>
</div>
```

Next, we want to use css in order to handle its inner contents like so:

```
/* css */
.collapsible-div p {
  display: none;
}
.collapsive-div.open p {
  display: block;
}
```

And last with jQuery, make this action work by clicking on the div elements itself and toggle the open class to toggle the display mode of p. Also remove the open class from each collapsible div in there to close the others when you open another one.

```
// javascript
$(".collapsible-div").click(function() {
  $(".collapsible-div").removeClass('open');
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

So what we do here is using css to control the visibility of the content paragraph with a class 'open'. And with javascript (jQuery) we toggle that class to toggle the `<p>` class 'open' when we click it! This is a minimal working example, I would recommend delegating the click action to an anchor also in the div, maybe to make an icon for communicating to the end user that this is a toggle-able panel. I hope this will help you! (I have not tested it, but I think it should work.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example. Upon clicking a div it will close all content of open divs and open the content of the clicked div. Let me know if you have any questions.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o5ppobae/

The CSS gives our content holding divs some default height so they stay clickable even when content is hidden, some space below each so they dont look like they run into each other and hides the initial content of each.

HTML:

```
<div class="main main-div1" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;"> 
<p> Content 1 </p> 
</div>
<div class="main main-div2" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;"> 
<p> Content 2 </p> 
</div>
<div class="main main-div3" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;"> 
<p> Content 3 </p> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    min-height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main p {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        // Attach div clicks
        $('.main').on('click',
            function () {
                // Find any open divs, remove open class and close content
                $('.main.open').removeClass('open').find('p').slideUp();

                // Add open class on new div and open content
                $(this).addClass('open').find('p').slideDown();
            }
        );
    }
);
```